# How to compare two dates in c#

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a textbox where i will enter date in mm/dd/yyyy format,i want to compare this textbox date with current date(sysdate) in javascript code in c#.How to do that??Example i enter 11/11/2011 which is future date and it must be checked with sysdate and print an message

Comment: If you could think about what you want to do before you ask it might be easier to answer your question.
What's your platform?

Comment: Have you not even considered `Date.Compare`? If you ever want to be a good programmer, you must be able to look that up yourself. In the documentation. In the internet. By looking at the declaration of `Date`. Et cetera. The really bad thing is that you already mentioned `Date` and `Compare` ...

Comment: "in javascript code in c#" - What does that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

example

```
DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "mm/dd/yyyy",null) > DateTime.Today
```

Comment: I want to do this thru javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateValue;
string dateString = textBox.Text;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue)) 
{
     // Use Date.CompareTo as you want to...

     int result = DateTime.Compare(dateValue, DateTime.Today);
     if (result > 0)
     {
          //Future Date 
     }
}
```